# Is the Moser-Tardos algorithm used in any real-world applications?

Tags: ds.algorithms, randomized-algorithms, application-of-theory

The Moser-Tardos algorithm can be used to construct algorithms for certain combinatorial problems. However, I'm curious about whether this algorithm is utilized in real-world systems (a SAT solver, for example) or if it serves solely as a theoretical research tool.

For example, many papers propose distributed versions of the Moser-Tardos algorithm, but are these algorithms actually used in real distributed systems?